# Problem with data file of Rocket Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

For a windows form application I want to use Rocket Framework from http://rocketframework.codeplex.com.

I downloaded Rocket Framework V 1.0.2. After that I located the datafile inside 'Release V 1.0.2\Release V 1.0.2\MainForm\DB'. Now I need to make a database in MS SQL Server to be used in the code. But the RocketDB data file has extension 'file' and I am not finding a way to make a database in MS SQL Management Studio.

I also searched in the code plex link http://rocketframework.codeplex.com but could not find the way to use it. Any one have the idea how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by generating the database itself from the entity model(.edmx) file. After that everything ran smoothly.